# Transform multiple columns from strings to dates

Tags: julia

I want to define a function that takes a dataframe (`df::DataFrame`) and the names of the columns to transform to dates (`cols::Vector{Symbol}`)

What I have is this:

```
function fixDateColumns(df::DataFrame, cols::Vector{Symbol})
    function stringsToDates(dates::Vector)
        Date.(dates, dateformat"yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS")
    end
    dates = stringsToDates(df[!, cols])
    df[!, cols] = dates
    return df
end
```

When calling this function like this:

```
fixDateColumns(df, [:Start_Date, :End_Date, :Recorded_Date])
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching (::var"#stringsToDates#11")(::DataFrame)
Closest candidates are:
  (::var"#stringsToDates#11")(::Vector
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `stringsToDates ` expects a single vector (column), while you are calling it with a tabular object...

Comment: Okay thank you! Should I just omit the type altogether? What is the fix here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
transform!(df, cols .=> ByRow(x -> Date(x, dateformat"yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS")) .=> cols)
```

or

```
df[!, cols] = Date.(df[!, cols], dateformat"yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS")
```

Comment: Thank you for the elegant solution!